# Facebook API - Accessing Information Through Graph API Without Access Token

Tags: facebook

My question is a feasability question and not a coding question.

I'm developing a website for an organisation who previously only used Facebook as their only online presence. The organisation now wishes to develop a website with a news section in which their own news is drawn from the notes they have posted in the notes section of their Facebook account (other related news from similar organisations is drawn from RSS feeds) - so as the same information appears both on their Facebook page and website, and so the organisation can continue to post their news in the same manner.

Having investigated this problem I have only been able to come up with a solution whereby the notes can only be displayed to a user who is currently logged in to Facebook (and therefore has a valid access token to access it via the Graph API).

Is it possible to view the notes without beng logged in to Facebook (and therefore not having an access token to do so)?

I'm not looking to develop a web application that accesses the users personal information or anything else, just simply display the notes that are posted on the Facebook account (which is publically accessable).

Any advice as to how to go about solving this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to do it via access token and proper installation of the app you can access those notes easily using curl (if the notes are available for the public) , you just have to go to the notes page which is like facebook.com/USERNAME/notes and from there you have to get the notes list using regEx and then browse each link and get the content by web scraping .

Good Luck !